# Can I make a UITabBarController size its tabs' viewControllers according to its own layout guides (non-IB)?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

(NB. This question is about iOS development **without** using the Interface Builder.)

Apple have a [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html) that says:

> Applications that use an opaque UINavigationController or UITabBarController automatically keep their content below the status bar.

When I saw this, I assumed it meant that when used as the root view controller for a whole app, the UITabBarController would automatically size the views of its tabs' view controllers so that they don't extend under the status bar.

However, creating an otherwise empty project with the code below in its AppDelegate suggests otherwise. The area under the status bar ends up red or blue, depending which tab you're on, not the white that is the underlying UIWindow's background colour.

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let vc1 = UIViewController()
    vc1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    vc1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .Bookmarks, tag: 1)

    let vc2 = UIViewController()
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    vc2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .Favorites, tag: 2)

    let tbc = UITabBarController()
    tbc.viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]

    window!.rootViewController = tbc
    window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

The UITabBarController has a topLayoutGuide that I could use to add explicit constraints to to keep the content below the status bar. Presumably something involving these guides (rather than hardcoding an offset of 20 somewhere) would be the "right way". However, in my real life situation vc1 and vc2 are supposed to be UITableViewControllers, so the only approaches I can see are:

1. Derive from UITabBarController and add constraints to manage the size of its tabs view controllers. Presumably these constraints would need to be added/removed as the user switches between the tabs. Sounds complicated, and I'm not sure how it would interact with whatever functionality in the UITabBarController is setting the contained views to their current size.
2. Create a custom view controller class to use for the tab view controllers, which contains the UITableViewController as a child and constrains its view to be within its own layout guides (which appear to be set correctly).

I'm leaning towards 2, but view controller containment seems an awful lot of fuss to achieve something that the Q&A seems to imply should be happening already. I'm new to iOS/Cocoa/Swift/Xcode/EverythingApple, and I'm sure there must be a better way.

**UPDATE:** Actually, looking more carefully at the simulator it seems the contained view controllers extend behind the tab bar as well. There must be something really basic I'm getting wrong here...

**UPDATE:** edgesForExtendedLayout looks promising, but setting it to UIRectEdge.None doesn't seem to stop the view extending under the status bar in my test.

**UPDATE:** Actually, setting edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdge.None on each of vc1 and vc2 in the example above does appear to prevent the views from extending under the tab bar, which is a step in the right direction. However, it has no effect as regards the status bar. The docs on this subject really are atrocious. I don't see how you're supposed to divine what is meant by "extended layout" or what the relationship betweem edgesForExtendedLayout and topLayoutGuide/bottomLayoutGuide is, except for trial and error, which seems to be what people have been resorting to.

**UPDATE:** This [excellent blog entry](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/61507315630/wrestling-with-status-bars-and-navigation-bars-on-ios-7) gives a lot more detail than the docs, and explains the behaviour I'm seeing. However, I still don't see a good solution yet. I can't insert an outermost view controller to hold everything in because the docs for UITabBarController say that you should never make it a child of another view controller - it needs to be the root. I suspect that the contentInset behaviour described in the blog's point 8 is supposed to give me what I really need, which is for the top of my UITableView's content to start off below the status bar. If Apple want me to allow the content to then scroll under the status bar, that's OK with me I suppose. However, currently the top of my table view starts off under the status bar text, which is just obviously wrong looking. Perhaps something is preventing the contentInset adjustments from working.

Answer (score 0):

I placed this in my viewDidLoad method to prevent the UITAbleView content from loading underneath the tab bar.  In my case the tab bar is at the top and I had to iterate to find the offset:

self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 0, 0, 0)

the general use case is:

self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#top: CGFloat#>, <#left: CGFloat#>, <#bottom: CGFloat#>, <#right: CGFloat#>)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this seems a hack to me. I don't feel I should be hardcoding things like the sizes of tab bars that the system is setting up on my behalf - it hardly seems future proof. Since your problem was with the tab bar rather than the status bar, you might be able to solve it more nicely with the edgesForExtendedLayout property mentioned in my last couple of updates.